# Tomcat 8 URL Rewrite

Tags: java, angularjs, apache, url-rewriting, tomcat8

I have an AngularJS webapp and Jersey backend. I need to setup URL rewriting, so everything except given exceptions will be rewritten to Angular's index.html.

Eg.:

```
http://my.domain.com/about will be rewritten
http://my.domain.com/photos/photo1.jpg will NOT be rewritten (file photo 1 exists)
http://my.domain.com/rest/myservice will be NOT be rewritten (it is a call to REST service)
```

I have set up the Tomcat 8 URL Rewrite Valve as follows:

in **conf/server.xml**

```
<Host name="my.domain.com" appBase="webapps/MyDomainServer" unpackWARs="true"
           autoDeploy="true"
           xmlValidation="false" xmlNamespaceAware="false">
  <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.rewrite.RewriteValve" />
  <!-- access logging, aliases,...-->
</Host>
```

in **conf/Catalina/my.domain.com/rewrite.config**

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} ^/rest.*
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteRule ^ index.html [L]
```

Tomcat ignores my rewrite settings, nothing is rewritten, no error/exception is in the log. What am I doing wrong? Thanks in advance.

I have tried to move RewriteValve to config.xml in META-INF and rewrite config to WEB-INF, but it behaved in the same way.

Comment: Can you'll provide solution for https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66472682/redirect-sub-domain-to-specific-mapping

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I have found the solution, problem was in wrong/faulty rewrite.config file.
Correct should be:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(css|img|js|partials|rest|favicon).*$
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [L]

RewriteRule ^.*$ /index.html [L,QSA]
```

On the first line are enumerated URIs which should not be rewritten. Everything else will be rewritten to index.html.

Comment: But why was it faulty? i have the same issue. %{REQUEST_FILENAME} is always NULL...

Comment: ... and SCRIPT_FILENAME is correct, but RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} -f complains about a missing leading / in the resource. Its a Windows system. So the path is C:\... without leading /

Comment: In our case, we used {REQUEST_URI} instead of (REQUEST_FILENAME}. We couldn't drop the rules completely because we were unable to load assets local to the application, but changing the !-f and !-d to use REQUEST_URI seems to be working, at least for now.

Answer (score 5):

Is this deployed as a java web app (WAR)?  You could implement this in your web.xml:

```
<servlet>
   <servlet-name>index</servlet-name>
   <jsp-file>/index.html</jsp-file>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
   <servlet-name>index</servlet-name>
   <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
   <url-pattern>/about</url-pattern>
   .. as many as you need ..
<servlet-mapping>
```

Comment: Thanks Nicholas, this seems to be an interesting option, but I have managed to solve it using rewrite. I had faulty rewrite.config file.

Comment: This is absolutely the wrong solution. The accepted answer is dynamic, where this answer is hardcoded

Comment: @Talador12, for certain circumstances, this works well and is appropriate.  Consider a Tomcat instance serving multiple war files.  The dynamic solution must be addressed to accommodate anything new and different.  This solution is self contained.

Answer (score 3):

I couldn't get this to work with the REQUEST_URI, and I didn't like having to whitelist specific files anyway, so I solved it in a [slightly different manner](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44847035/511976).