# Using Angular CLI unable to load images on tomcat server without doing image bundling

Tags: angular, tomcat, angular-cli

I am working on Angular 4/ Angular CLI project.

Folder Structure on Tomcat server when deploy.

```
tomcat/
------Webapp/
-----------assets/bgr.svg
```

WebApp folder

[image: WebApp Folder]

main.bundle.js

```
// module
exports.push([module.i, ".myimg{\r\n    background: url('/assets/bgr.svg') no-repeat center center fixed;\r\n    background-size: cover;\r\n}", ""]);
```

Index.html

```
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Cliskeleton</title>
  <base href="./">
```

base href is './' because i am using tomcat to deploy my application.

angular.cli

```
 "assets": [
        "assets",
        "favicon.ico"
      ],
```

app.component.css

```
.myimg{
    background: url('~/assets/bgr.svg') no-repeat center center fixed;
}
```

i can use relative path ('../assets/bgr.svg') here. But relative path bundles image and placed it in dist folder and i have hundred of images so it makes dist folder very big. So I don't want to use relative path.

I have tried 'assets/bgr.svg' also but i get an error as below.

```
ERROR in ./src/app/app.component.css
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './assets/bgr.svg' in 'D:\Research\CLISkeleton\cliskeleton\src\app'
 @ ./src/app/app.component.css 6:61-88
 @ ./src/app/app.component.ts
 @ ./src/app/app.module.ts
 @ ./src/main.ts
 @ multi webpack-dev-server/client?http://localhost:4300 ./src/main.ts
```

Is there any way such that i can place all my images in 'assets' folder and reference it.

Comment: you can use `baseHref="/"` on tomcat though..

Comment: I have tried same but it did not work. Can you share some reference link

Comment: Check here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34619751/tomcat-8-url-rewrite-issues/44847035#44847035

Comment: I will try it out. But does it solve my problem?

Comment: You need to set the base href path when you are building your app: "ng build --prod --bh /warFileName/" (without ".war").