# Tomcat 8.5 rewrite Valve to redirect root request to specific webapp

Tags: java, tomcat, url-rewriting, tomcat8.5

I have a requirement to allow certain URLs without a context to be forwarded to specific webapp.

So, I have a webapp "app1" deployed and working. The following URL `http://localhost:8080/app1/ping` is working fine. In `$CATALINA_HOME/webapps` I only have `app1.war`, no `ROOT.war`

I want to configure the rewrite valve to redirect `http://localhost:8080/ping` to `/app1/ping`

In my `server.xml` I have enabled the Rewrite valve. Then I created `$CATALINA_HOME/conf/Catalina/localhost/rewrite.config` with the following content:

```
RewriteRule ^/ping /app1/ping
```

In the Tomcat logfile I can see the rule is invoked:

```
25-Nov-2019 09:02:11.442 FINE [http-nio-8080-exec-1] org.apache.catalina.valves.rewrite.RewriteValve.invoke Rewrote /ping as /app1/ping with rule pattern ^/ping
```

But nevertheless I get a 404 in the browser for `/ping` (but not for `/app1/ping`)

In the access log I can see both request show up with the same URL, but the redirected one (the first line in the below log) is listed with a 404

```
0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 [25/Nov/2019:09:02:11 +0100] "GET /app1/ping HTTP/1.1" 404 1078
0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 [25/Nov/2019:09:02:23 +0100] "GET /app1/ping HTTP/1.1" 200 4
```

What am I missing here?

I am using Tomcat 8.5.40 together with Oracle's JDK 8 on Windows 10

If I add a redirect flag to the rule:

```
RewriteRule ^/ping /app1/ping [R]
```

then I get a NPE inside Tomcat:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
  at org.apache.catalina.connector.Response.sendRedirect(Response.java:1318)
  at org.apache.catalina.connector.Response.sendRedirect(Response.java:1288)
  at org.apache.catalina.valves.rewrite.RewriteValve.invoke(RewriteValve.java:435)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
  at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
  at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:609)
  at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
  at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:810)
  at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1506)
  at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
  at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Comment: Did you check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34619751/tomcat-8-url-rewrite-issues

Comment: @user7294900: that is about redirecting inside a single webapp. I am essentially trying to do that _before_ my webapp is accessed, adding a context to a URL without a context (without using a ROOT.war). I am also not enabling the valve for a specific context (because it should work _without_ one)

Comment: I'm having the same problem. 
Strange thing is that I had simulated the very same thing you're doing on my Windows development machine using Tomcat 8.5.58 and it worked, but Ubuntu Server's Tomcat 8.5.39-1ubuntu1~18.04.3 has the problem you're seeing. So it might be a bug in Tomcat?

Answer (score 2):

The problem here is that there is no context bound to the request. Make sure to configure some (empty) ROOT context that the request gets bound to.