# subdomain realtime mapping in apache tomcat

Tags: java, apache, .htaccess, tomcat

i need to map a sub-domain (which is created by user, it means dynamically) to a same login page but i want to get the subdomain parameter through address bar

for exmaple

```
www.xyz.koopsz.com

www.abc.koopsz.com

www.mno.koopsz.com
```

these urls should redirect to the login page with paramater xyz or mno etc

- **What i did**

i thought i can map it in .htaccess **www.koopsz.com/abc** then will rewrite it to **abc.koopsz.com**

after so many effors i get to know that

**apache tomcat doesn't support htaceess**

now how can i solve this problem in Apache tomcat i read about virtual hosting but everytime when user add i have to make changes in server.xml i need it in a runtime. please help me out.

Comment: I suppose "htaceess" is just a typo here on SO and not in your real error message?

Comment: Is there a reason you need to alter the URL at all? Why not just let the user access the application using `www.foo.koopsz.com` and use the default host for every request? You can get the hostname from the request to discover the `foo` at any time... it doesn't need to be at the beginning of the hostname.

Comment: @ChristopherSchultz in www.foo.koopsz.com .. foo is the subdomain which is created by user at runtime

Comment: If DNS isn't an issue, you not just point all hostnames at the same server (or cluster) and use the hostname the user uses to detect which configuration to use (presumably, you want to use the same application but a different database or whatever depending upon which user it is)? You wouldn't need to change the Tomcat configuration from the default: use just the default host for everything with a single application deployed.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are looking for [Tomcat's rewrite valve](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/rewrite.html). Other questions here more directly explain how to set this up. From [Tomcat 8 URL Rewrite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28767585/tomcat-8-url-rewrite) we see:
in **conf/server.xml**

```
<Host name="my.domain.com" appBase="webapps/MyDomainServer" unpackWARs="true"
           autoDeploy="true"
           xmlValidation="false" xmlNamespaceAware="false">
  <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.rewrite.RewriteValve" />
  <!-- access logging, aliases,...-->
</Host>
```

and in **conf/Catalina/my.domain.com/rewrite.config**

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(css|img|js|partials|rest|favicon).*$
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [L]

RewriteRule ^.*$ /index.html [L,QSA]
```

You should mostly be able to plug in whatever htaccess directives you were using for rewrite.

Comment: Can i make it dynamically?